# Catboost: Cannot calc metric which requires logits for absolute values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm using catboost for my model and I'm getting the error as below to the following code:

```
from catboost import Pool, CatBoostClassifier, cv

#Split data
train = data[:split]
test = data[split:]

# Get variables for a model
x = train.drop(["Survived"], axis=1)
y = train["Survived"]

#Do train data splitting
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x,y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

cat_features = np.where(x.dtypes != float)[0]

cat = CatBoostClassifier(one_hot_max_size=7, iterations=21, random_seed=42, use_best_model=True, eval_metric='Accuracy')

cat.fit(X_train, y_train, cat_features = cat_features, eval_set=(X_test, y_test))
pred = cat.predict(X_test)

pool = Pool(X_train, y_train, cat_features=cat_features)
cv_scores = cv(pool, cat.get_params(), fold_count=10, plot=True)
print('CV score: {:.5f}'.format(cv_scores['test-Accuracy-mean'].values[-1]))
print('The test accuracy is :{:.6f}'.format(accuracy_score(y_test, cat.predict(X_test))))
```

...which raises:

> ---> 23 cv_scores = cv(pool, cat.get_params(), fold_count=10)
>
> CatBoostError: catboost/libs/metrics/metric.cpp:5069: Cannot calc
>   metric which requires logits for absolute values.

Help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the parameter `loss_function='Logloss'` inside the `CatBoostClassifier()`. This issue is described [here](https://github.com/catboost/catboost/issues/467) and was supposedly fixed but now it appeared again. I will reopen this issue because this is clearly a bug.

Comment: Ouuuh, test accuracy .88 on Titanic. That's it! Thanks, @Pavlo!